# How to examine the contents of the Flash Player cache?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

In my case I want to load the signed framework RSLs into the flash player cache. Seems to work, but how can I validate, that the swz is really being loaded into the flash player cache?

On my Linux box I tried to find some kind of file in ~/.macromedia, but was not successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of notes that might help:

0> The file you're looking for might be in: /home/user_name/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache/ or 
/home/username/.macromedia/Flash_Player/Logs/

1> There might be a low-level way to see if an RSL was loaded via the cache. However, generally, the behavior is simply left to the player (cough) to do the right thing (cough). If the RSL is in the cache - it should do the deal (cough).

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Broken links removed as per noted comments below (thanks!)

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. This helped a lot. There are several bugs with FlashPlayer 9.x and Linux. Another problem is that the signature cannot be verified. So far I am using FlashPlayer 10.x and had no more problems so far. I hope that this is also true for this bug.

Comment: To validate if it was cached you can also run some HTTP debugging proxy (Charles is a good one) to see if the RSL file is loaded only once or many times when you refresh.

Comment: The link does not work anymore ([Here's a decent write up](http://www.diybl.com/course/1%5Fweb/webjs/2008410/109445.html))